# Settings not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, software-center, settings, system-settings

I'm a new user of Ubuntu 20.04,
whenever i try to open settings,it opens, but don't show up at all, unless I use a second screen.

if not then it will like this:

Now settings is open
[image: now settings is open )]

I tried using terminal to reinstall Gnome-Control-Center using these command:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

then

`gnome-control-center display`

`gnome-control-center`

and it maybe worked for some users, but not for me.

anyone knows what the reason may be or a different solution?

btw my Gnome-Control-Center has some issues that i couldnt fix even with reisntalling, so i started using flathub in my software to avoid the issue, but couldnt fix settings

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this:

Go into terminal and type:

```
xrandr --auto
```

If that didn't work try typing:

```
xrandr --current
```

You will get a list containing `vga`, `vga1`... with most of them displaying `disconnected`.

Ignore `LVDS-1 connected` and search for the other one that has `connected`; most likely it will be `VGA-1`.

If so then type the following command:

```
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output VGA-1 --off
```

Please note that I have given `VGA-1` as it was in my case, but you may have to change it to whatever you find connected other than lvds-1.